# Hide folder structure on server for images with nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, filesystems

I have the following folder hierarchy on my server:
`/var/images/d/d8/d82fa6c3eed/image.png`

The directory structure is created from an MD5 hash and broken up into sub-folders.

I would like to serve the images to web users with Nginx, but don't want to expose the directory structure. For example, I do **not** want to serve the files like this:
`http://domain.tld/d/d8/d82fa6c3eed/image.png`

I want to serve it something like:
`http://domain.tld/b/4324re3fg34f6td/image.png`

I am also using the nginx `secure link` module, but you have to specify the directory to get the image, like this:
`http://domain.tld/b/<secure link MD5 hash>/path/to/file.png`

that gets rewritten into:
`http://domain.tld/images/path/to/file.png?md5=<secure link md5>`

and I don't want to specify the actual specific directory path on my file system to get the file. I was thinking along the following lines:

- the client can send some kind of MD5 value that represents the directory path to file, and NGINX will insert / every N character. Is this possible?
- send the directory path encoded in base64, and have NGINX decode it and internally redirect there. And this?
- maybe use an extra module for this, like openresty module?

Can I achieve this..?

My nginx config:

```
server {
    ..
    root /var/www/html;
    ..
    location /b/ {
        rewrite ^/b/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/(.*)$ /images/$2/$3?md5=$1 last;
    }
    location /images/ {
        internal;
        secure_link $arg_md5;
        secure_link_md5 '$uri mysecretkey';
        if($secure_link = "") { return 404; }
        if($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `secure_link` so I cannot comment on that part of your proposal. But an obvious error in your configuration is that you should be using `rewrite...last` if you want the rewritten URI to be processed by the `location /images/` block. The `break` suffix, causes the URI to be processed within the same location.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: I changed it to `last`, but `break` seemed to work too.